# winapi: LsaCallAuthenticationPackage returns STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL

Tags: windows, winapi, rpc, local-security-authority

I'm new with Lsa and came accross to this problem. Here is my code:

```
LsaConnectUntrusted(&Lsa)
LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(Lsa, &PacketName, &PackId)
printf("Lsa return -> %x.\n", LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(Lsa, PackId, buf, Size, &resp, &respSize, &st));
```

The output I get is `0xc0000001` which means `STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL`. On windows website It doesn't provide information what specifically this error means. I did a little research and it turns out it's RPC connection failure. I tried [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.07.howitworks.aspx) but it didn't help. Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely to be an RPC problem, what specifically made you think it was? My best guess is that the authentication package didn't like the contents of the buffer you sent it.